# NLP analysis advice

Tags: database, methods, sentiment-analysis, survey, topic-modeling

Working on an NLP project and would really benefit from any expert help.

I'm looking to narrow down my options and select the most appropriate analysis methods and techniques for a project I'm working on. My question relates to what I should do in relation to the data I have. Any help (for a newbie) is very appreciated.

My data: Open text, short string data responses to a survey question. I have multiple survey responses, each survey has a high number of respondents (3K+) although a relatively low number respond to the question (typically 50 per survey). The responses are short (typically one line/sentence response), but I have about 20 surveys, so a reasonable corpus to work with.

Here's what I was planning (high level): Preprocess and clean the data, run some descriptives on the text data itself (BOWS, word frequency, maybe tf-idf, word clouds), then attempt some Topic Modelling and maybe Sentiment Analysis.

My main questions as I work my way through this massive learning process:

Would this type of data set warrant any particular Topic Modelling or Sentiment Analysis techniques?
Are there any obvious or less obvious limitations or considerations I should keep in mind, as a result of the data I've got?
Are there any clear step by step guides you can recommend? (I've been dipping in and out of a lot course and reading, but any similar experiences or examples would be invaluable).

I appreciate this is a bit text heavy and asking a lot, but any help and support would be really fantastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little bit late to the party, but in terms of topic modeling, the best starting point is LDA.  There are a bunch of implementations of it (the best is [MALLET](https://mimno.github.io/Mallet/)), and it is relatively easy to understand.  There are a bunch of topic models designed for short texts such as open-ended survey responses, including some that I helped design.  Our models can be found in the python package [GDTM](https://github.com/GU-DataLab/gdtm).  Take a look at NLDA, which is designed for short texts, and Guided Topic Model (GTM), which is also designed for short texts, but which allows you to provide seed topics if you already know some important topics.  Have fun :)

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you, and your timing is actually perfect. I'm loving what I've achieved with LDA so far and really looking forward to advancing on it, so this is a great resource.

Answer (score 0):

I am replying as a self-starter in NLP like yourself, so I have come across similar considerations in my projects too. First of all, it sounds like the corpus you have sounds adequate for the analyses you intend to carry out, however the best test is really to apply a topic model and see what kind of results you get.

For topic modelling, I find using Gensim quite handy and comprehensive:
https://nicharuc.github.io/topic_modeling/#topic=10&lambda=1&term= - provides a more comfortable intro to LDA including ways to evaluate the results e.g. coherence values
and sensitivity analysis.

For ease of simplicity, Top2Vec provides a simple way of embedding a topic model: https://github.com/ddangelov/Top2Vec - do note that the corpus needs to be large enough for it to conduct anything (let alone something useful).

Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: Really appreciate this...I'm working through my pre-processing and initial text analysis, but this seems really helpful so I'll come back and let you know how it's all going. Cheers!